# ¿Como detectar el final de mi documento con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que quisiera saber cuando el usuario ve la vista principal de mi aplicacion y este llega al final, el pie de pagina debería de aparecer de forma vistosa, actualmente tengo varias lineas de código en juqery que debería de mandarme un alert cuando llegue al final, pero me hace lo contrario y me manda la alerta cuando estoy hasta arriba.

Código actual:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("END!");
   }
});
```

Comment: Me parece que esta respuesta resuelve el mismo problema que expones aquí, revisa este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/193467/86010

Answer (score 2):

Lo que ocurre es que no es exacto el valor de `$(window).scrollTop()` por lo que al sumar el alto `$(window).height()` de la ventana no dará el alto `$(document).height()` del documento, te recomiendo manejarlo con un margen de error.

Ejemplo:

```js
const MARGEN = .1;

$(function(){
 $(window).on("scroll",endPage)
})
function endPage(){
 if(MARGEN > $(document).height() - $(window).scrollTop() - $(window).height()) {
  console.log("Fin de la Pagina");
 }
}
```

```css
#divID {
 height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divID"></div>
```