# verificar si has llegado al final de la página con scroll()

Tags: jquery

Estoy utilizando este script de jQuery pero funciona al reves

```
var heightPage = $(document).height();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) == heightPage) {
            alert("final de la página");
    }      
});
```

se supone que debería ejecutar el `alert` cuando llegue al final de la página pero lo ejecuta cuando llegas al principio

Comment: Eh probado su código, y funciona sin ningún problema. Sería bueno que comparta el código html y css también para encontrar el origen del problema.

Comment: Lo he probado en firefox y chrome pero en ninguno funcionó cómo esperaba, es un sistema muy amplio con varios `script` vinculados y html dinamico, lo que puedo aportar es que modifiqué el script y ahora funciona cómo estaba esperando

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He logrado el objetivo gracias a una publicación en inglés de github el script es el siguiente:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
        alert("Ha llegado al final de la página");
    }
});
```

Es un poco más compleja (más lineas de código y más operaciones) pero en mi extraño caso funcionó cómo necesitaba, es una alternativa para la misma función

Link del Gist en Github: https://gist.github.com/toshimaru/6102647

> Actualización:

### Encontrar el final del scroll de un div

Últimamente me surgió la necesidad de algo similar pero en lugar de toda la página necesité encontrar el final del scroll de un sólo div.

El código es JavaScript puro

```js
function esElFinal() {
  let element = document.getElementById("scroll");

  if (element.offsetHeight + element.scrollTop >= element.scrollHeight) {
    alert("Llegamos al final del bloque");
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto
}

.content {
  height: 100px
}

.red {
  background: red
}

.blue {
  background: blue
}

.green {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div onscroll="esElFinal()" id="scroll" class="container">
  <div class="content red"></div>
  <div class="content blue"></div>
  <div class="content green"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Creo que e podido conseguirlo con vanilla javascript, espero que a otra persona le resulte util:

```
var elm =document.querySelector('#datos-scroll');

addEventListener('scroll', function(){

    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= elm.offsetHeight){

        console.log('LLegamos al final del bloque');

    }
});`
```